# Problem using VSCode for OSGEO4W and Python development

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, osgeo

I want to use VSCode as editor for my OSGEO4W development. I can write and debug and run my programm, but the "outline"-window (which is pretty necessary) on the left side is not working.
When looking at the Python-Output there is the following error-message:

`InvalidPythonEnvironment: Could not get version information for 'C:\\OSGEO4~1\\bin\\python.exe': InternalError(u'The subprocess C:\\OSGEO4~1\\bin\\python.exe has crashed (EOFError(), stderr=).',)`

I am using this batchfile for starting VSCode:

```
rem @echo off
set OSGWO4W_ROOT=C:\OSGeo4W64

REM Setting HOME is necessary for VSCode
REM in order to find the global .gitignore-file
SET HOME=H:\

call "%~dp0\o4w_env.bat"
@echo off

path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin
path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Qt4\bin
path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python27\Scripts

SET PYTHONPATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\python27\lib;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\python27\lib\site-packages;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin;%PYSC_DIR%\Lib;C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\python\Python27\site-packages;

path %PATH%;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
path %PATH%;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin
path %PATH%;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Windows\system32;c:\Windows;c\OSGeo4W64\bin;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\


set QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT:\=/%/apps/qgis
set GDAL_FILENAME_IS_UTF8=YES
rem Set VSI cache to be used as buffer, see #6448
set VSI_CACHE=TRUE
set VSI_CACHE_SIZE=1000000

set QT_PLUGIN_PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qt5\plugins

path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%

start /d "C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\" Code.exe
```

When using VSCode with the standard-python-installation everything works fine.

VSCode-Version: 1.47.2
Python: 2.7.16 64bit

Comment: The problem seems to arrise in the command:```C:\OSGEO4~1\bin\python.exe c:\Users\<username>\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.7.94776\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py pip --version```

Comment: Found out, that when using the python3-environment from OSGEO4W it works. Any ideas how to make it work also with python 2.7.14?

Comment: Would you mention the way you configured this.

Comment: @rs_punia Do you mean the python-3 environment? Because the python 2 just does not work (partly works, but is not supported).